# Conditional Cumulative Sum of Multiple Rows in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, aggregate

I am trying to find the cumulative sum for four consecutive rows in a dataframe based on a condition.

The new column (**'veh_time_TOT'**) is a sum of four consecutive '**veh_time(s)**' values and the condition is '**Day_type**': Weekend or Weekday.

Here is how the data is now set up:

```
    veh-time(s) distance(m) Day_type
0   72  379.0   Weekday
1   70  379.0   Weekday
2   50  379.0   Weekday
3   60  379.0   Weekday
4   70  379.0   Weekday
5   65  379.0   Weekday
6   30  379.0   Weekend
7   35  379.0   Weekend
8   30  379.0   Weekend
9   30  379.0   Weekend
10  20  379.0   Weekend
```

Here is the desired output:

```
    veh-time(s) distance(m) Day_type    veh_time_TOT
0   72  379.0   Weekday        0
1   70  379.0   Weekday        0
2   50  379.0   Weekday        0
3   60  379.0   Weekday        252
4   70  379.0   Weekday        250
5   65  379.0   Weekday        245
6   30  379.0   Weekend        0
7   35  379.0   Weekend        0
8   30  379.0   Weekend        0
9   30  379.0   Weekend        125
10  20  379.0   Weekend        115
```

I've tried several things but the only thing I could find is using the .cumsum function which only finds the sum for 2 consecutive rows. 
The zeros in the "**veh_time_TOT**" are there because there haven't been 4 rows yet to make up the sum.

My thinking that this would be a combination of .cumsum and conditional if statement that goes on a loop.

What do you guys think? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: After 10th index what should be output if it is `weekday` does it need to continue adding from 245 or it should start from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I took to get the desired column:

- First, I set up your example DataFrame.
- Next, I defined the three columns of interest (the column whose
  values will be the basis of the calculation, the column used for
  comparison, and the column name for the calculated quantity.
- After that, I find all the rows that are eligible for this calculation (previous 4 rows have the same value for `col_compare`).
- I then iterate over this slice of the original DataFrame, summing the previous four values of `col_val`.
- Lastly, I create the new column with the desired name of `col_name_new`

  - Initialize its values to zero
  - Fill the eligible locations with the list we generated in the previous step:

Here is my code, feel free to ask Q's in the comments!

```
import pandas as pd

# Setup

cols = ['veh-time(s)', 'distance(m)', 'Day_type']

data= [[72,  379.0 ,  'Weekday'],
       [70,  379.0 ,  'Weekday'],
       [50,  379.0 ,  'Weekday'],
       [60,  379.0 ,  'Weekday'],
       [70,  379.0 ,  'Weekday'],
       [65,  379.0 ,  'Weekday'],
       [30,  379.0 ,  'Weekend'],
       [35,  379.0 ,  'Weekend'],
       [30,  379.0 ,  'Weekend'],
       [30,  379.0 ,  'Weekend'],
       [20,  379.0 ,  'Weekend']]


df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=cols )

# Define columns for potential future generalization

col_val='veh-time(s)'
col_compare='Day_type'
col_name_new = 'veh_time_TOT'

# DataFrame slice of rows eligible for calculation

cut_prev_four =  (df[col_compare].shift(1)==df[col_compare]) \
                &(df[col_compare].shift(2)==df[col_compare].shift(1)) \
                &(df[col_compare].shift(3)==df[col_compare].shift(2))

df_consecutive = df[cut_prev_four]

# Perform calculation on eligible rows. Store in list

prev_four_list = []
for i,row in df_consecutive.iterrows():
    prev_four_vals = df.iloc[i-3:i+1][col_val].values
    print(i, prev_four_vals, sum(prev_four_vals) )
    prev_four_list.append(sum(prev_four_vals))

# Set new column to the calculated values

df[col_name_new] = 0
df.loc[cut_prev_four, col_name_new] = prev_four_list
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer so I get them sweet, sweet internet points